# Convert row in Excel to custom entity

Tags: c#, excel

In order to read data from an Excel sheet I'm using a third-party dll that has one method `GetCell` and its return type is `Object`. One row in the Excel sheet contains multiple columns so after reading one row I'm stuck with a lot of Objects. These objects should be the properties of a custom entity. For instance, if the Excel sheets has the two columns `Name` and `DateOfBirth`, then the values should map to the following Person entity

```
class Person{
public string Name {get; set;}
public DateTime DateOfBirth {get; set;}
}
```

Is there a simple way of doing this conversion? Since I have to read many different Excel sheets, the conversion can not be hard-coded.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using C#.  One possibility I could think of was keeping a `List<List<string>> setsoflabels` in which you would hold the names of the columns associated with a particular entity.

So the first entry in `setsoflabels` would be a list comprised of `"Name"` and `"DateofBirth"`.

Then, you could have a `List<object> types` of which the first entry was `Person`.

(The second entry in `setsoflabels` could be a list comprised of `"Make"` and `"Model"`, and the second entry in `types` could be `Car`, assuming you have a class with that name)

If a particular sheet's headings matched up with a particular index of `setsoflabels` then check that same index in `types` to get the type.

It's essentially like having a dictionary, but I don't believe you can have a dictionary with a `List` as a key.  You could probably whip up a custom data structure based on what I have outlined above if you are going to need it repeatedly.